youtube video player is loading when already loaded player video when recylerview scrolls up and scrolls down android kotlin why this happens
class MediaAdapter(
    private val mediaList: List<VideoItem>,
    private val activity: FragmentActivity // Use FragmentActivity context for lifecycle support
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MediaAdapter.MediaViewHolder>() {

    class MediaViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val thumbnail: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaThumbnail)
        val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaTitle)
        val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaDescription)
        val webView: WebView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.webView)
        val btnWebFullScreen: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullscreenIcon)
        val playIcon: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playIcon)
        var youtubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view)
        val progressBar: ProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        var youtubePlayerDuration:Float = 0.0F


        init {
            // Register FullscreenListener

            youtubePlayerView.addFullscreenListener(object : FullscreenListener {
                override fun onEnterFullscreen(fullscreenView: View, exitFullscreen: () -> Unit) {
                    // Handle entering fullscreen
                    println("full screen listener")

                    // Extract the video ID or URL to pass it to the full-screen activity
                    val videoId = youtubePlayerView.tag as? String

                    println("video Id url... $videoId")
                    if (videoId != null) {
                        println("duration id seconds $youtubePlayerDuration")
                        val tracker = YouTubePlayerTracker()
                        youtubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(tracker)
                        tracker.state
                        tracker.currentSecond
                        tracker.videoDuration
                        tracker.videoId
                        println("duration value  ${tracker.currentSecond}")
                        println("current State ${tracker.state}")
                        println("current videoId ${tracker.videoId}")
                        val intent = Intent(itemView.context, FullScreenYoutubeViewActivity::class.java).apply {
                            putExtra("VIDEO_SOURCE", "YOUTUBE")
                            putExtra("VIDEO_ID_OR_URL", videoId)
                            putExtra("VIDEO_SEC",youtubePlayerDuration)
                        }
                        itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Unable to enter fullscreen mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

                override fun onExitFullscreen() {
                    // Handle exiting fullscreen
                }
            })
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MediaViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_item_media, parent, false)
        return MediaViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MediaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val videoItem = mediaList[position]
        holder.webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
        holder.webView.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.youtubePlayerView.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.thumbnail.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        // Load the thumbnail image (e.g., using Glide)
        Glide.with(activity)
            .load(videoItem.thumbnail)
            .into(holder.thumbnail)

        holder.title.text = videoItem.title
        holder.description.text = videoItem.description
        holder.webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        // Determine if the URL is an embedded video or direct MP4 link
        val isEmbeddedVideo = videoItem.videoUrl.contains("www.youtube.com")
        if (!isEmbeddedVideo) {
            loadWebViewVideo(holder, videoItem)
        } else {
            loadYouTubeVideo(holder, videoItem.videoUrl)
        }
    }

    private fun loadWebViewVideo(holder: MediaViewHolder, videoItem: VideoItem) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        holder.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE  // Show the loader
        holder.thumbnail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        holder.webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
        holder.webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT

        // Check if the WebView is already displaying the correct content
        if (holder.webView.url != videoItem.videoUrl) {
            holder.webView.loadUrl(videoItem.videoUrl)
        }


        holder.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.thumbnail.visibility = View.GONE
//                holder.webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        holder.webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onShowCustomView(view: View?, callback: CustomViewCallback?) {
                if (view is FrameLayout) {
                    enterFullscreenMode(view, callback, videoItem.videoUrl)
                }
            }

            override fun onHideCustomView() {
                exitFullscreenMode()
            }
        }

        holder.btnWebFullScreen.setOnClickListener {
            holder.webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.querySelector('video').currentTime;})()") { result ->
                val currentPosition = result.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
                val intent = Intent(activity, FullscreenVideoActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("videoUrl", videoItem.videoUrl)
                    putExtra("playbackPosition", currentPosition)
                }
                activity.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
    

    // new video play play only clicking the button
    private fun loadYouTubeVideo(holder: MediaViewHolder, videoUrlItem: String) {
        holder.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        try {
            val videoId = extractVideoId(videoUrlItem)
            holder.youtubePlayerView.enableAutomaticInitialization = false
            if (videoId != null) {
                val youtubePlayerListener = object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                    override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                        if (holder.youtubePlayerView.tag != videoId) {
                            holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE  // Hide the loader
                            holder.youtubePlayerView.tag = videoId
                            holder.thumbnail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            holder.youtubePlayerView.visibility = View.GONE
                            holder.webView.visibility = View.GONE

                            // Set up play button click listener
                            holder.playIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            holder.playIcon.setOnClickListener {
                                holder.thumbnail.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.playIcon.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.youtubePlayerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0f) // Cue the video at 0 seconds
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                val iFramePlayerOptions = IFramePlayerOptions.Builder()
                    .controls(1)
                    .fullscreen(1)
                    .build()

                holder.youtubePlayerView.initialize(youtubePlayerListener, iFramePlayerOptions)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Invalid YouTube URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Exception: $e")
        }
    }

    private fun extractVideoId(url: String): String? {
        return when {
            url.contains("youtube.com/watch") -> {
                val pattern = Regex("v=([^&]+)")
                pattern.find(url)?.groupValues?.get(1)
            }
            url.contains("youtu.be/") -> {
                val pattern = Regex("youtu\\.be/([^?&]+)")
                pattern.find(url)?.groupValues?.get(1)
            }
            url.contains("youtube.com/embed/") -> {
                val pattern = Regex("embed/([^?&]+)")
                pattern.find(url)?.groupValues?.get(1)
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mediaList.size
    }

    private fun enterFullscreenMode(
        view: View?,
        callback: WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback?,
        videoUrl: String
    ) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, FullscreenVideoActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("videoUrl", videoUrl)
        }
        activity.startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun exitFullscreenMode() {
        println("exit full screen")
    }

}


here in this code my youtube player video loads first time play correctly but when i scroll down and again scroll up the list first played videos are still loading and  it takes more time loading sometimes its not play videos whats the issue here in the youtube player video implementation please check the code
here i am using this library for implementation
implementation("com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:12.1.0")
